# what's the difference between these two python functions

Tags: python

today I had an interview and got a question that I answered wrong.
Here's the question:

```
def gen():
    return [lambda x: x + i for i in range(4)]

print([m(1) for m in gen()])
```

The result is [4, 4, 4, 4]. My answer was [1, 2, 3, 4].
I also ran the following code.

```
def gen():
    return (lambda x: x + i for i in range(4))

print([m(1) for m in gen()])
```

The result is [1, 2, 3, 4].
Could anyone explain? I am so confused.

Comment: The first one has [ ] brackets and the second (). Using [ ] all the numbers are always set to the last value added.

Comment: @Nathan i was curious about the answer, could you make one with more details ? Also upvoted, found that interesting.

Comment: Good question and with good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268439/python-list-comprehension-with-lambdas

Comment: Using `[]`, all the lambdas are created immediately, but when they are evaluated in the second list comprehension, the `i` from the first list comprehension (which is closed over) is equal to `3` - this is all as explained in the linked duplicates. Using `()`, the lambdas are created on demand when the `print` line's list comprehension runs, so each `lambda` is getting created immediately before being called, with the corresponding `i` value.

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet that uses `()` is  a generator.
Used to save memory

Look at [PEP-289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)