# Shared and localized variables in Python closures

Tags: python, closures, shared-resource

Closures in Python behave in an “odd” way, so to say.
Consider the following code snippet where I have tried to build a list of closures based on `foo` in two ways: In `bad_closure`, closures are built ‘on the fly’, while in `good_closure` the closures are built by a helper function:

```
def foo(d):
    return d + 1

def bad_closure():
    ''' shares resources implicitly '''

    # list of 5 closures
    # `i` is shared between all closures
    cls = [lambda : foo(i) for i in range(5)]
    return cls

def good_closure():
    ''' no resource sharing '''

    def mk_cl(i):
        ''' helper to make a closure'''
        c_ = lambda : foo(i)
        return c_

    # list of 5 closures
    # each closure has its own `i`
    cls = [mk_cl(i) for i in range(5)]
    return cls

#--- TEST ---
bs = bad_closure()
print([f() for f in bs]) # output: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

gs = good_closure()
print([f() for f in gs]) # output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The results are astoundingly different. It seems that in `bad_closure`, the closures take a *fixed* `i` each, but they all *share* the *same* `i` which updated by each iteration (and finally takes the value `5`)! In contrast, in `good_closure`, `i`'s are separate — as I expect.

I'd like to see what is happening behind the scenes and why.

Comment: This is a known [python gotcha](https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/). Solution is `cls = [lambda x=i: foo(x) for i in range(5)]`

Comment: more info still: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268482/4819449