# Python Telegram bot adding handlers from list

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm having trouble adding command handlers on the run, here's an example:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

updater = Updater(token)
items = [
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3)
]

for i in range(len(items)):
    def dummy_func(bot, update):
        print(items[i][1])

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        CommandHandler(items[i][0], dummy_func)
    )

updater.start_polling()
```

I would expect `/a` to print `1` in my console for example, but instead `3` is printed for a, b or c. I thought maybe the function is stored every time in the same spot in memory and tried storing the callbacks in a list but it didn't help.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tldr;

This problem does not belong to telegram bots or `python-telegram-bot` lib.
It's just a *feature* of Python language.
The reason behind that is somewhat similar to famous [lambda functions in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268439/python-list-comprehension-with-lambdas) python behaviour.

---

#### Test case

Consider this slightly simplified version of your script:

```
items = [
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3)
]

handlers = []  # think of dispatcher handlers as a list
for i in range(len(items)):
    def dummy_func():  # <--- closure
        print(items[i][1])  

    handlers.append(dummy_func)  # somewhat similar to dispatcher.add_handler()

for f in handlers:  # let's see the results
    f()
```

It outputs exactly the same result as you got:

> `3`
> `3`
> `3`

---

#### Explanation

You get same results because you create a **closure** by defining `dummy_func` inside `for` loop and using `items[i][1]` inside the func itself.

The problem is that you probably don't expect that `dummy_func` will reference variable `i` only when this particular function **is actually being executed**.

And since it is executed after `for` loop is finished, the value of `i` is its last value in loop. So all your functions refer to the same value of `i`, which is `2`, and `items[i][1]` will always be `3` in this case.

---

#### Links

[Nice article](https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/) about scoping and closures in Python.
GitHub [gist](https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/700292) about closures.